# ReactJS: Checking for redux state and conditional rendering?

Tags: reactjs

So, in our application, we are mapping state to props and then checking for a status response from redux to conditionally render the component or a loading component...

This feels wrong.

If our component is a "Smart Component" should we conditionally render from redux or is there a better option?

```
    <MainLayout
      screens={Status === types.SELECT_LIST_SUCCESS ? renderListPage : <Spin />}
    />
```

Comment: what is renderListPage

Comment: instead of `types.SELECT_LIST_SUCCESS ` what about using some flags

Comment: @RajatDhoot renderListPage is a const that holds all the divs for the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do so using shouldComponentUpdate(), it is considered to be an advanced practice in React.

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output
>   is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default
>   behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast
>   majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.
>
> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or
>   state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called
>   for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used.
>
> Returning false does not prevent child components from re-rendering
>   when their state changes.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate